# Python looping range vs looping array

Tags: python

```
for i in range(-1, 2):
  pass
```

vs

```
for i in (-1, 0, 1):
  pass
```

What option is preferable? In therms of readability or standards.

Comment: Which python version? range works differently from 2.x to 3.x

Comment: `range(-1, 2)` is more readable; performance and memory usage difference are negligible

Comment: why do u think there will be a speed difference and what are u trying to achieve

Comment: what if the sequence should contain 300 numbers? Will you type it manually? Of course, `range()`

Comment: Have you tested it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `range()` is slower than using a list, as generator has to yield each value, while the list already holds all the elements. Because of this, `range()` will take up less memory than a list.

In terms of readability, `range()` is usually easier to read than a list, `range()` tells you which integers it'll loop trough, while the list has a lot of values, so if there is a value that's skipped, it'll be hard to notice.

The standards say `range()` is the better option and should be used almost always if looping certain amount of times is needed.

Answer (score 0):

if you know how to remember your list means you can go with list..

eg: in your case you have `[-1,0,1]` here you can remember easily...

lets,

consider you want to loop this list -> `[-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4]` will you try this or below one?

```
>>> range(-4,5)
[-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**range()** will help you to generate dynamic list...

if you want which is best means,
you should think your usecase..

if you gonna use **list once** go with **xrange**
xrange will return **generator** which consume less memory than range.. because

`range` returns a **Python list** object and `xrange` returns an **xrange object** so you can use it once..

Comment: `xrange` does not return a generator.

Comment: yes changed.. thanks